# WinRAR how to know immediately if a compressed file is broken or incompletely downloaded by command line

Tags: command-line, winrar

I have `WinRAR` and using `Windows 7` OS.

It shows errors immediately like "Cannot open < FileName >" for the files which downloaded incompletely or broken when we open.

But when I search for command line solution to know the compressed file's status (broken or incomplete) I get the solution which advices to use **"T"** command of winRAR command line commands which **EXTRACTS** the whole file.

So is there any way to know the file status (broken or incomplete) **immediately** (like WinRAR) by command line without extracting?

Answer (score 0):

#### advises to use `T` option of the command line which EXTRACTS the whole file.

Actually it doesn't extract the whole file:

> **Command T - test archived files**
>
> This command **performs a dummy file extraction, writing nothing to the output stream**, in order to validate the specified file(s).

<sup>(emphasis mine)</sup>

Source [Command T - test archive files - WinRAR Documentation](https://documentation.help/WinRAR/HELPCmdT.htm)

Comment: I am not the downvoter. But I value your opinion. Yes. You are correct. It writes nothing to the output stream. But it takes time depends on file size. I did a test with 800MB rar file with "T" command. It took 8 seconds. That is the thing I want to reduce.

Comment: It has to **read** the file to know if it is broken.